# Truth value of a statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

How do I prove the following statement?

> For all $\forall x \in R $ there exist $\exists y\in R$ such that $y^6-xy^2=-x^2$

How do I approach this? Thank you.

Comment: Note: "$\forall$" means "for all" and "$\exists$" means "there exists", so there's no need to write "for all $\forall$" when you mean "for all" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. For any negativ number $x$ the left side is positiv but the rigth side is negativ.

Answer (score 2):

This is no such $y$ for $x=-1$

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP wants more an general way to approach these kind of problems.

The general approach is :

0) Before anything else check if the statement is wellformed, a not wellformed statement can only lead you astray, if the statement is not wellformed try to make wellformed  before you go further.

If you can not make it wellformed, just note that and don't go further.

1) The statement is false if there is a true countermodel
(in your case can you find some x where there is no y)
It doesn't matter if for every other x there is an y, even if there is just one x where there is no y  then the statement is false. Try to find such an x, write down the x and that the statement is false and because of soundness it should not be possible to prove it.

Only if you cannot find such a counter model:

2) The statement is true if and only if such a counter model cannot exist.

(an example of such a statement $\forall x  ( x \in N \to  ( \exists y\in N \land y = x + 1 )) $ ), try to prove that for every x there is an y.

3) if you cannot decide which of 1) or 2) is true then the statement is undecided.
write down that you could not decide it and why.

GOOD LUCK